# Showing a subset is bounded/has least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

I'm newly learning real analysis and can't understand this problem

Take a set S. Consider the partially ordered set $(2^S,\subseteq)$.

Now consider any $B\subset2^S$. Show that B is bounded and has a least upper bound.

I'm confused by exactly what this means. How is this subset bounded?

Comment: Every subset of $S$ is bounded by $S$.

Answer (score 2):

$B$ is a family of subsets of $S$. No matter what family it is, $b\subseteq S$ for each $b\in B$, so $S$ is an upper bound for $S$ with respect to the partial order $\subseteq$. What is the **least** upper bound of $B$, i.e., the smallest subset of $S$ that contains every member of $B$ as a subset?

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is bounded above because the set $S$ is an upper bound.

$B$ is bounded below because the set $\varnothing$ is a lower bound.

In order to prove there is a least upper bound for $B$ we can show it explicitly, it is $\bigcup\limits_{A\in B} A$. It then remains to prove this set satisfies the necessary conditions.